# Copy files over network

Tags: networking, performance, copy, traffic

we use one windows 2003 server to sync files between two other windows servers. I assume that the whole traffic goes through the server initializing the sync.

If so, is there a way to trigger a copy between the 2 other machines without routing all through the first server?

Thank you!
Regards,
Uwe

Comment: What method are you using to sync the files? Windows File Copy? Or a specific application? Need more details.

Comment: It's using an old version of synchromat (.com). So I assume it's just windows file copy.

Comment: The way to do this on *nix computers is through ssh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to take the middle server out of the loop, you'll need to get one of the other two servers to initiate the copy. A combination of [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) (as suggested by [moshen](https://serverfault.com/users/3607/moshen)) plus [RoboCopy](http://www.microsoft.com/Downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=9d467a69-57ff-4ae7-96ee-b18c4790cffd&displaylang=en) would do the trick efficiently and quickly.

RoboCopy has a bunch of command-line switches that make this kind of sync easy to do - just be sure to test thoroughly **before** you start mirroring deletes (`/PURGE` or `/MIR`), else you can purge both directories in the blink of an eye!

Depending on your network infrastructure, you might be interested in the `/IPG:n` switch, as it forces RoboCopy to wait between packets, allowing other network traffic to get through.

Comment: Always have the data backed up before testing anything ^^

Comment: Indeed. When I screwed up my RoboCopy settings, I managed to nuke both my master copy AND my primary backup in one go. Was very glad I had another backup that was both *up-to-date* and *offline* to use for restoration.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) to initiate the copy remotely.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add a scheduled task on the server you'd like to initiate the copy process?

Another way to remotely start a process n a remote machine is to have a Windows Service wrapper around the executable and trigger it with the `net start` command - it supports calling remote servers.

Answer (score 0):

how about taking an extra step and implementing DFS?